# Submerging to avoid storm damage

Tags: underwater, shipbuilding

The land is full, there are no roads, and cars can fly. Some spend their whole lives in a single square mile. Life isn't entirely miserable for the average person, but trust me. You wouldn't choose that life. The rich have houses, but even they have to live cheek to jowl with their neighbours.

So floating houses have been built. Each house has a section above water on which to land a car, enjoy the sun etc., but most of the house is below sea level for stability. There's a lot of rising and falling, but you get sea legs eventually.

There's one problem, when there's a storm the house becomes dangerous. Throwing its occupants around violently. To combat this the designers make the houses submersible.

The question is: How far must the house submerge to avoid the storm? Such that the occupant could carry on moving around in the house without being tossed about? EDIT removed extra questions.

Comment: Hi Richard, please limit your question to just one question. I looks like your getting excited there at the end, and you've thrown on a bunch of follow up questions which would get your post closed. If you've ever been to the sea, you know that you can go under the wave to avoid being tossed and turned. However you need to make sure your low enough to not get sucked into the wave as well (Its really disorientating). I don't know the numbers, so I'll leave that as a comment for someone else who might know more.

Comment: Yeah... I realise that the house will need to be submerged 10's of metres potentially... I'm really looking for the practical minimum depth so I can think about what that pressure would mean for the house design.

Answer (score 2):

Funnily enough, I have considered the idea of vessels that temporarily submerge to avoid storms before! I suggest that the depth required to avoid perturbation by a storm is what is known as the "Storm Wave Base". It's the depth below which there will be no movement of the water caused by the storm above.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_base

Comment: The houses are 10 miles off coast.. so they're in deep water.. so all we have to worry about is huge waves.